# Node.js dns module's resolveCname returns outdated record intermittently

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

I am using node.js' dns module to resolve domains for CNAME records: [Node.js DNS](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html).

I found that dns' resolveCname returns outdated record intermittently.

Here is my scenario:

1. I have a domain example.com, and I have created a CNAME record for
   mail.example.com;
2. call resolveCname on mail.example.com, and it returns correct
   result;
3. remove the CNAME record for mail.example.com, and wait a while
   (~2mins), so that the DNS update can take time to take effect;
4. now call resolveCname again and it starts to behave weirdly: each time I call it, it randomly return either:
   ENOTFOUND which means the record doesn't exist; or the old record.

Does it look like a cache-related issue? How can I have it return the correct record consistently?

Thanks!

Comment: DNS is designed to be cached. The only way to retrieve uncached results is to query the authoritative DNS servers for the domain.

Comment: But randomly swinging between 2 distinct results doesn't seem correct caching behavior to me.

Comment: You probably have two DNS servers configured (which is quite common), on your first request only one was contacted and had cached the result.

Comment: Yes, I do have 2 DNS servers. So how do I solve this issue? My goal is to return the latest updated record as quickly as possible for good UX. Returning random record like this causes confusion on the user's end at best.

Comment: Then you need to query the authoritative DNS servers for the domain.

Comment: I am not sure what you are building, but this might give you some ideas https://www.digwebinterface.com/

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!